# Find a file which is 30 minutes old

Tags: unix, time, find

How can I find the file which is of 30 minutes old in `/bin/ksh`?

Comment: Run them and see what happens

Comment: **No difference**. Both will invoke undefined behavior!

Comment: I barelly can find the sense in your second loop. And the 2nd argument which stands for true/false condition, what are you trying to achive?

Comment: I ran the code and found no difference but I am not sure what is happened in those two.

Comment: If you insist on using the second loop you must reverse the order of the tests in the loop condition. You want to use `n < MAX && gets(names[n])` so the loop stops when `n == MAX` __before__ you call `gets(names[n])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first for loop runs gets(..) 3 times, the second 4 times but the last without the body of the for loop

Comment: At the first lap of the loop, undefined behavior is invoked as he tries to store things through an uninitialized pointer, which doesn't point at allocated memory. What happens after that is all a guess. Most likely the program will crash and burn.

Comment: @Lundin: Are you sure? There are two arrays in this code, `names[]` and `nameptr[]`, but this code doesn't show how the `names[]` array is defined or initialized.

Comment: names[n] has to be a valid pointer, but there is no declaration and initialization shown. So it is all a speculation.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: **Please tell me you'll never ever use that in production code. It's a pile of cr*p.**

Regarding your question for differences between the two, let's see.

In the first loop you are checking the condition before using `gets()`, which means the loop is executed three times.

In the second loop you are using `gets`before checking the loop condition and therefore executing it four times. The loop itself is never executed or we would have a problem with our array bounds.

To my surprise, both loops run without complaining(well, when executing, there is this "warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe." message, but oh well; what's not about the program?).

For reference, I used this as reference(please note that I tried my best to make it... runnable):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 3

int main(){
    char names[MAX][MAX];
    char *nameptr[MAX];
    int n;
    for(n = 0; n < MAX; n++){
        nameptr[n] = gets(names[n]);
        printf("%s", nameptr[n]);
    }

    for(n = 0; gets(names[n]) && n < MAX; n++){
        nameptr[n] = names[n];
        printf("%s", nameptr[n]);
    }

    free(nameptr);
    return 0;
}
```

This is likely to be the worst code I've ever written, but that's okay. My Mac will have to endure that. As said, the program actually runs. If you look closely, you notice that all the inputs are repeated except the last one(because that time `printf()`is never called).

But what does valgrind tell us(a memory checker)? This is not really related to the question, but it's what you get for messing with your memory.

When I run `valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out`, this is the summary:

```
==12822== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12822==     in use at exit: 33,265 bytes in 376 blocks
==12822==   total heap usage: 453 allocs, 77 frees, 39,233 bytes allocated
==12822== 
==12822== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12822==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12822==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12822==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12822==    still reachable: 8,192 bytes in 2 blocks
==12822==         suppressed: 25,073 bytes in 374 blocks
==12822== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
```

FYI, when I remove the call to `free()`(I am really using it without *alloc, ain't I?), this is what happens:

```
==12818== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12818==     in use at exit: 33,265 bytes in 376 blocks
==12818==   total heap usage: 453 allocs, 77 frees, 39,233 bytes allocated
==12818== 
==12818== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12818==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12818==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12818==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12818==    still reachable: 8,192 bytes in 2 blocks
==12818==         suppressed: 25,073 bytes in 374 blocks
```

Exactly identical. Strange, huh? Well, not so much, because nothing ever is explicitly allocated, so how could it be freed? I was about to measure runtime-efficiency, but I really am too lazy.

Again, **this code is really, really, really bad practice.**

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubt. Even though it is a crap question.

Comment: questions are never crap. answers are. code is - most of the time. it happens to be that this is very crappy code, but it's wonderful if you're here to learn, because we learn from mistakes.